# Will there be any official LINQ like lambda based library for C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, linq, lambda

Given C++ gained lambdas with C++11, will there be any LINQ like higher order function library officially supported later? Or is there already such a library used in production quality code?

Obviously I'm not expecting the SQL-like expression tree based LINQ query syntax in C++. I am talking about the lambda based one. So, no new language feature in needed in C++'11, just a library will do.

Comment: With LINQ you mean LINQ to Objects? Or did you mean the whole LINQ incl. XML and SQL?

Comment: @mbx Yes. I mean LINQ-to-objects only.

Comment: btw, SQL-like expression tree based LINQ query syntax is not something impossible in C++, stuff like boost::proto let people write DSEL now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to predict the future.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ-to-objects is already supported in the Standard library and has been since it's inception. The syntax is just a bit different- it was never intended to emulate SQL and has way too many iterators in it. You can make it more reminiscent without too big a hassle.

Edit: When actually *attempting* to make it more reminiscent without too big a hassle, I determined that it actually could be a significant hassle. It is, however, still completely possible.

Comment: _The syntax is just a bit different_ is that a euphemism?!

Comment: @mbx: No, that's how it is. And as my post demonstrates, it's trivial to alter that syntax.

Comment: You might want to explain how to actually *use* this?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that it wasn't exactly a finished product.

Answer (score 1):

*Notes : For C++2011 there is not such functionality.
Fortunately, the next C++ should include a filesystem library (see boost::filesystem) so you can guess that such a database library will not be standardized soon.*

There are several (and some recent) discussions on the boost mailing list about such library. Several people are pointing to potential boost-like libraries like [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) and [CPPDB](http://art-blog.no-ip.info/sql/cppdb/).

Also, I don't see how lambdas can help for such a functionality. Lambdas are still code, not EDSL constructs.

Comment: I didn't Linq-to-sql with Linq. It was about the lambda based method chaining.

Answer (score 0):

There's ODB which is interesting.

see the sample code from the [ODB wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODB_%28C++%29) that searches for all people called Doe younger than 30 (age and last are DB columns, directly mapped to a class, this is done by the ODB compiler to it always keeps automatically generated classes in sync with the DB schema, without having to modify a DB->code mapping definition file or assembly). I like it because of that, having had to maintain an Entity Framework assembly.

```
  transaction t(db.begin ());

  result r(db.query<person>(query::last == "Doe" && query::age < 30));

  for (result::iterator i (r.begin ()); i != r.end (); ++i)
  {
    cout << "Hello, " << i->first () << endl;
  }

  t.commit ();
```